# Launching web url with Session

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am developing HTML web page. I am creating session id in that.

I want to use the same session id for opening that web site through my iOS app as well.

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myserver.com:8080/Test/TestPage";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Is it possible to launch a web url using *Session ID* appended in iOS?

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be to do with objective-c, ios or uiwebview as it's more to do with how you handle the request on the other side (Server Side).

Answer (score -1):

If I am not understanding it in the wrong way, you just want to add some parameters to your request, in this case sessionID. In this case you should do this:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.myserver.com:8080/Test/TestPage"];
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"sessionID=%@", @"val1"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [webView loadRequest: request];
```

On the other way around, you can use for example AFNetworking Library that will allow you to do things like this:

```
NSDictionary * parameters = @{@"sessionID"     : @"123"};
NSMutableURLRequest * mutableRequest = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                          path:@"http://www.myserver.com:8080/Test/TestPage"
                                                    parameters:parameters];
```

Anyways, @Popeye is right, you would need to manage this somehow in your server.